# Creating a two series chart in VBA using nested for loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts

I have some basic VBA which automates the creation of line charts based on a given range with one chart created per line. I want to add a second line which displays and average and have the data in another sheet. I have inserted images below showing that the layout of both tables of data is the same.

Original plotted data:
[image: Original plotted data]

New series data:
[image: New series data]

The code I currently have is:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim chrtname As String
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LastColumn2 As Long 

LastRow = 136
LastColumn = 43
'Looping
For i = 118 To LastRow
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    'Adds chart to the sheet
    Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart(Width:=500).Chart
    'sets the chart type
    chrt.ChartType = xlLine

    'setting data source
    With Sheets("Charts Data")
        chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
    End With

    'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet
    chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
    'chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i) * chrt.ChartArea.Height
    
    'Set a chart title
    chrt.HasTitle = True
    chrtname = Sheets("Charts Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
    chrt.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    chrt.ChartTitle.Select
    chrt.ChartTitle.Text = chrtname
    
    'Add x axis labels
    chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Charts Data'!$C$92:$AQ$92"
    
    'Trying to add chart legend
    chrt.HasLegend = True
    chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Hospital Site"
    
    **'Trying to add national medians
    LastRow2 = 43
    LastColumn2 = 66
    For j = 28 To LastRow2
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = Sheets("Data").Range(.Cells(j, 3), .Cells(j, LastColumn))
        End With**
    
    Next

        Next

End Sub
```

I've tried a couple of different ways but can't work out how to get the vba to first loop through the first set of data to create the initial chart, and then pull data from the first iteration of the second loop before moving on to the creation of the second chart with second row down of data used from each table to create a two series chart.

Apologies for the confusing wording and crude VBA knowledge.

Comment: Use `F8` key to step through the code line-by-line. Which line isn't doing what you expect it to?

Comment: It is the part I highlighted with '**' where I try to add the National Medians row by row it throws an error regarding the object.